# Make Event Background Color Unique on a Per-event Basis

Tags: fullcalendar, expressionengine

I am sure there is a simple solution, but after reading existing posts and the documentation, I haven't been able to locate it just yet.  This is my first post here, so any help is much appreciated.

I am integrating the FullCalendar with ExpressionEngine and the Calendar module for EE, and I have events rendering in FancyBox.

My only remaining issue is that the background of each event is the same color.  What I am wanting to accomplish is on any given day, make multiple events have a different background color to identify the event as unique.  In the documentation, it explains how to change the background color, but it's an "all-or-nothing" solution.

I also attempted to tweak the styles, but this made every day cell have the background color, rather than the actual individual events.

The code that builds the calendar and populates events from EE is listed as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
       left: 'prev,next',
       center: 'title',
       right: ''
    },
    editable: false,
    events: [ {}
      {exp:calendar:events event_id="{segment_3}" sort="asc" dynamic="off"}
        {occurrences}
          ,{title: '{event_title}',
          url: '{url_title_path="path_to/event/"}',
          start: new Date({occurrence_start_date format="%Y,%n-1,%j"}),
          end:  new Date({occurrence_end_date format="%Y,%n-1,%j"}),
          allDay: true,}
        {/occurrences}
      {/exp:calendar:events}
    ],
    eventClick: function(event) {
        if (event.url) {
        $("a").fancybox(event.url);
            return false;
        }
    }
});  });
```

This would be simple to do if the events were manually being populated, but the data is coming from ExpressionEngine, rather than being hard-coded.

Any thoughts on how to make each event on a per-day basis render with a different background color than any of the other events listed for that same day?

Thanks for reading!!!

Answer (score 0):

The current version of fullCalendar has a property on an event object '.backgroundColor' which can be set to change the background colour of that event.  Of course you'd have to write some code to set up the background colours to all be unique within a day.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  I am using the current version of fullCalendar and I know about this property, but where I'm stuck is setting each event within one day because it varies from day to day.  This does help though and gives me an idea of where I need to do some work.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using the css3 nth child selectors here. This will allow CSS to automagically change the colors for you. See: http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

You would of course need to target the appropriate elements, but without seeing the full DOM it will be very difficult for us to help with that here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eventAfterAllRender`which is triggered after all events have finished rendering in the fullCalendar from both source.

```
eventAfterAllRender: function( view ) {
    var allevents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
}
```

Now, with the `allevents` object, you can do whatever toy wish.

Here is the one I took for me:

```
eventAfterAllRender: function(view) {
                    var allevents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
                    var countevents = 0;
                    if( allevents.length ) {
                        countevents = countevents + allevents.length;
                    }
                    if(!countevents) {
                        // alert('event count is'+countevents);
                        console.log('event count is',countevents);
                    }
                }
```

One of my friend was able to get the id of duplicate events and now I can delete the duplicate event within a loop as:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', allevents[i].id);
```

Now it is up to you. Very sorry because I am running a busy schedule nowadays. I'm glad if someone would generate a proper solution for Mr. Lane from this(even by editing this answer).

Thank you.